# Server returning illegal capacity -1

Tags: java, android, sockets

here im gonna post a perfect example of sending and receiving images,musics, videos or anything through sockets so who ever needs can use it. its almost perfect. it does the job, no matter how many files you have in the target it counts them and sends them to the java server, but atlast im receiving an exception on the server side :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

i really dont know what is that,but i appreciate if you help so i compelete this for myself and any one else who finds himself in need of one. thanks

Android Cliend :

```
 package com.example.imagesender;

//File imagefile = new File(filepath);
//  FileInputStream fis = null;
//       try {
//           fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
//      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 //          System.out.println("file not found");
 //        e.printStackTrace();
 //    }

 // Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
//  imgbyte = new byte [(int)filepath.length()];
//   imv.setImageBitmap(bm);
//  Log.d("ClientActivity","length:"+imgbyte);




public class AccountCreator extends Activity {  
    private Button send;  

    private Socket socket;  
    private File f,fdst;  
    private FileInputStream fin,fises;  
    private static Context context;  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.mes_registerpage);  
        send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendpic);  
      //  sendWan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendWan);  
        AccountCreator.context = getApplicationContext();  

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  

            public void onClick(View view){  

                this.doit();
            }
                class myAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>{


                                 @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(String...urls){    
                try {  
                    socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1500);  
                    System.out.println(socket);  
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");  


                    File fil=new 
 File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/");  
                      System.out.println(fil);
                    File[] Files=fil.listFiles();  
                    System.out.println(Files);
                    for (int count=0;count < Files.length;count ++){  
                        System.out.println(Files[count].getName());  

                    }  

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();    
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);   

                    dos.writeInt(Files.length);  

                    for (int count=0;count<Files.length;count ++){  
                          dos.writeUTF(Files[count].getName());  

                    }  
                    for (int count=0;count<Files.length;count ++){  

                          int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();  
                          dos.writeInt(filesize);  
                    }  

                    for (int count=0;count<Files.length;count ++){  

                    int filesize = (int) Files[count].length();  
                    byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];  

                    FileInputStream fis = new  
 FileInputStream(Files[count].toString());    
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);    

                    //Sending file name and file size to the server    
                    bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //This line is important  
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);     
                    dos.flush();   

                    //close socket connection  
                    //socket.close();  

                }  

                           //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Transfer file 
is completed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                     socket.close();  
                }  
                catch(Exception e){  
                    System.out.println("Error::"+e);  
                    //System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                    //e.printStackTrace();  
                    //Log.i("******* :( ", "UnknownHostException");  
                }
                return null;

            }  
                }



                protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                }


public void doit(){
myAsync sync = new myAsync();
sync.execute();
}
        });}

    }
```

and the server side:

```
 public class Server {  

    /** 
     * @param args 
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,EOFException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
     FileOutputStream fos;  
     BufferedOutputStream bos;  
     OutputStream output;  
     DataOutputStream dos;  
     int len;  
     int smblen;   
     InputStream in;  
     DataInputStream clientData;  
     BufferedInputStream clientBuff;  


    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1500);  
    Socket clientSocket = null;  
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  


        in = clientSocket.getInputStream(); //used    

       clientData = new DataInputStream(in); //use    
       clientBuff = new BufferedInputStream(in); //use    
      int N=1;
         while(N==1){    

            System.out.println("Starting...");    

               int fileSize = clientData.read();        
                        fileSize = (fileSize > 0) ? fileSize:0;      


                        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);          
                        List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);

                for (int count=0;count < fileSize;count ++){  

                        sizes.add(clientData.readInt());  
                }  

               for (int count =0;count < fileSize ;count ++){     

                  len=sizes.get(count);  

                System.out.println("File Size ="+len);  

                //output = new FileOutputStream("C:/share/" + fileName);  
                output = new FileOutputStream("D://Users/" + files.get(count));  
                dos=new DataOutputStream(output);  
                bos=new BufferedOutputStream(output);  

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];    

                bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //This line is important  

                while (len > 0 && (smblen = clientData.read(buffer)) > 0) {   
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, smblen);   
                      len = len - smblen;  
                      dos.flush();  
                    }    
            N=2;
              }   
       }  

      } //end loop   

 }
```

thanks in advance

the stacktrace:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Server.main(Server.java:49)
```

Comment: please include the whole stack trace =)

Comment: The problem is `DataInputStream read` returns `the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.` and  you are using `int fileSize = clientData.read();` as `ArrayList` initializer. ArrayList will `IllegalArgumentException - if the specified initial capacity is negative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass a negative value to the `ArrayList` constructor. You can also use the diamond operator (in Java 7+), and you might prefer to use the `List` interface. So, something like this -

```
int fileSize = clientData.read();
fileSize = (fileSize > 0) ? fileSize : 0;             // guard against negatives.
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);         // Using List and <>
List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);
```

Comment: yes, seems problem was this + using JRE1.6 , changed it to 1.7 and It worked, thanks all, wish could accept all answers. i just update the code when im done fixing it all

Comment: but now im in some sort of unending loop,images are received , but server keeps printing the starting...

Comment: Update your client to actually send the count of files... -1 will now become 0, and your inner loops won't run (since count = 0).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
int fileSize = clientData.read();  

ArrayList<File>files=new ArrayList<File>(fileSize); //store list of  filename from client directory  
ArrayList<Integer>sizes = new ArrayList<Integer>(fileSize); //store file size from client
```

`read` method returns -1 on end of stream.  You're not checking for this and attempting to use it as the initial capacity of your ArrayList's.  Add proper error checking - and you'll be fine.